# Android deprecated method backward-compatible

Tags: android

My app uses a method that was deprecated since Android 2.1 with a different method and I would like to make it work from 1.5 to 2.2.  Is there a way for my app to determine which Android version the user has and call the correct method based on that?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the device SDK version using inbuilt classes available in Android and then put a if else condition around it.But i am not sure if its the recommended approach...

```
int sdkversion=  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

Comment: thanks :)  I looked into that a little more and found that version.sdk_int is actually not available on cupcake, lol. but, version.sdk is.  its just a string instead of an int:

int sdkversion= Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK)